# How to update chart only on unique data in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

Following the sample code [HERE](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data) I have a function that fetch json data and load it as a chart event to dynamically display data using HighCharts.

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch_json_data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; 
                chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);                                       
                // call it again after one second               
                setTimeout(requestData, 1000);                  
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Problem is that every time the ajax function returned the same value every second, the graph looks flat and I dont want that to happen because it created a stepped lines instead of the normal graph everytime data changed sometime.

I was thinking of putting a check so that `setTimeout(requestData, 1000);` will only be called if `point` contains a different value.

Unfortunately I cant make it to work so maybe there is a way to control it so that the graph only updates whenever there is a change in `point`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TL;DR **Give it short term memory!** Pass the point as an argument to your recursive function, and check
>   the new point against it before calling it again.

Yes you can call your `requestData` function only when you receive a new `point` from the service. Essentially what you have is a recursive function, and you can call it conditionally by passing it the `point` back as an argument.

So conceptually (without being able to run your code due to lack of your data), and example would look like this:

```
function requestData(oldPoint) { // <--- Passing it a oldPoint to remember
    $.ajax({
        url: 'fetch_json_data.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; 

                if(point[1] !== oldPoint[1]){       //<---- Check if this is a new point
                  chart.series[0].addPoint(point, true, shift);    // <---- update chart if you received a new point
                  setTimeout(function(){
                    requestData(point);    // <---- call the requestData with new point -- as old point for next call
                  }, 1000);  
                }
                else{
                  setTimeout(function(){
                    requestData(oldPoint);// <---- because you received a duplicate point in this call, try again with old point
                  },1000);
                }                                       
                // call it again after one second               

        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

Now the very first call from chart's `load` event will look like `requestData([null,null])`. At first `oldPoint` argument will be `null`, and hence it will always add first point, and then from there on every recursion will check for uniqueness of point before adding to series. If the `point` is same as `oldPoint` it will just re-request the new point!

Comment: thanks but I can't seem it to work. the point comes as json object like this `[1491974707000,-2.15]` and I only want to check the 2nd element for uniqueness before the graph should update.

Comment: Okay then just check the second element like so: `if(point[1] !== oldPoint[1])`  but remember the change the initial call to `requestData([null,null])` . I have updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

Set an empty variable outside of requestData() such as lastPoint.

Before adding the newly fetched point, get that variable and compare it to what you just got. If they're the same, then skip adding the point until the next round. If it's different, add the point and set lastPoint to the new value.

Comment: Setting global variable like that is a very is a very bad coding practice. Especially when you can easily avoid it by just using the recursion that is already taking place.